# Cannot add custom user data to scaffolded ASP.NET Core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to figure out how to add custom profile data into a razor web app using the dotnet cli tools. This web app is targeting the dotnet core 3.0 sdk.  However I keep running into an error when I try to run the code generator tool.

I've restored all the packages I  saw in the error message but it's not enough.

These are the packages I have added to the project.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.0.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The expected results is to have the application tell me that it worked and for files to be created. Instead I keep getting this error in the console.

```
Account.Manage.Index : The term 'Account.Manage.Index' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:74
+ ... tor identity -u WebApp1User -fi Account.Register;Account.Manage.Index
+                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Account.Manage.Index:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I don't have the index page or any of the other major pages made besides Register. Oddly enough my user and db context did generate. I'm confused as to why this is happening. The directions on this site mention nothing about it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=netcore-cli

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```bsh
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -u WebApp1User --files "Account.Register;Account.Manage.Index"
```

Looks like there may be a typo in those docs. You can check here for more complete instructions: [Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=netcore-cli)

**UPDATE:**

There's no typo in the docs. See [Chris Pratt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654031/chris-pratt)'s comment below for the reason you're getting that error in PowerShell.

Comment: It's not a typo. The command is written to be run in something like bash or the Windows command line. PowerShell has a special meaning for semicolons: it indicates the start of a new command. So here, since it's not quoted, PowerShell thinks you want to run the first command up to the semicolon and then another `Account.Manage.Index` command.

Comment: @Chris Pratt That makes more sense - thanks for the explanation.